# Least number of circles that can fill a box

Tags: geometry

My application is this: I have a robot with a laser scanner on top, and I am trying to program it in such a way that it moves through rectangular areas so that it has maximum view of everything in the box.

The laser scanner has a field of view of 270 degrees, for convenience, if I assume it as a full circle, is there a mathematical way of computing the least number of circles I need to fill to traverse most of the box? Such that if the robot moves through the centers of these circles, it can cover majority of the box. Any suggestions/directions about this would be helpful.

Thank you!

Sai

Comment: For some reason, it doesn't let me write 'Hello' in the beginning..

Comment: Wait; a robot or a shark?

Comment: Haha, a friggin' robot with a friggin' laser beam attached to its head.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bh7bYNAHXxw

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a fixed range limit giving the circles?  If you are moving around the box trying to get within a certain distance of each point, it is hard to beat a back and forth scan.  Let $r$ be the radius.  Start at one edge $r$ from the corner and move parallel to the other edge.  When you come to the far side, move along the edge by $2r$ and go back, etc.

Comment: Hi, yes, there is a specific range for the scanner, let's say 1m, in a 5mx4m box. What you said was my initial guess, but I was wondering if there's a way to construct something like a smooth curve on the fly, depending on how far the range is from the boundaries of the box at a given instant, and what would be the most efficient point to go to next, etc.

Comment: Basically, if you want to get the corners, you need to do something like this.  Circles don't fill rectangles very nicely.

Comment: I see. Yes, essentially, your approach would let me traverse the box completely. The reason I was talking about 'least circles to fill the rectangle' was because I thought I was missing a better approach that would require me to travel less but let me cover more. Thanks for the reply.